# pyplot window doesn't plot things

Tags: matplotlib

```
x=[[ 0.          0.00221864  0.00488273 ..., -0.03966467 -0.03691193  -0.03415696]]
y=[[  0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e-03   1.00000000e-02 ...,   7.06000000e+00, 
       7.06500000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
plt.plot(x,y)  
plt.show()
```

The data both have 1415 columns.
Then the figure looks like the following
[image]

Why does it show nothing?
Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use nested lists to plot your data.
The following plots nothing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [[1,2,3,4]]
y = [[2,3,1,4]]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

While this plots the values as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [2,3,1,4]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can if `x = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]; y = [[2],[3],[1],[4]]`

Comment: The issue is that the length is computed from the outermost list. Notice that the axis limits are actually correct in the first case even though nothing shows up.